# Create custom forms in SharePoint Designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, list, custom-form

I need to make some custom forms because I need to be able to add, edit and delete rows from multiple lists on one page.

The link below suggests that I use "Data Views and Forms" in the SP Designer 2013 Ribbon, but I'm unable to find it. Does this exist in SP Designer 2013 or was it removed for some reason?

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/sharepoint-designer-help/create-data-forms-using-sharepoint-designer-HA101631630.aspx

I guess it's possible that a custom form is not the correct solution also. If it isn't, how can I modify both my classSessions and enrolledStudents in the same page? I have a calendar on which I can plan sessions of a class and on the new and edit forms, I would also like to be able to see all the students enrolled in that class, as well as add or remove them.

Thanks in advance for any help provided!

EDIT: 
So I think I am most of the way to a solution. By adding a web part to the page, I am able to access the quick edit on another list, which is pretty close to what I wanted. If I could also have the search bar for that list, I think it would be sufficient. Right now, it is showing me all of several hundred enrolledStudents for all sorts of other classes. If I had the search bar then we could filter this to only include students enrolled in the class session I'm actually looking at.

Comment: can you confirm that the site has turned on permissions for SP Designer editing and access? More information about it - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2592376

Comment: Yes, I am the site owner.